# Media Query in CSS Not working as expected

Tags: html, wordpress, css, media-queries

I need to show two different logos on my site depending on the device width. 
If the screen size of device is 300px or less than it, i need to show small logo.

Site: http://www.geekdashboard.com/

Logo.png -> http://www.geekdashboard.com/wp-content/themes/geekdashboard/images/logo.png

logo-small.png ->
http://www.geekdashboard.com/wp-content/themes/geekdashboard/images/logo-small.png

CSS:

```
.header-image .site-title > a {
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat left;
    float: left;
    min-height: 90px;
    width: 425px;
}
```

and CSS for small width devices as follows

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

.header-image .site-title > a {
    background: url(images/logo-small.png) no-repeat left!important;
    width: 300px!important;
}

}
```

This code is not working as expected for me. I can still see the logo.png even on devices with screen size less than 300px
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share demo link?

Comment: Site is already live here http://www.geekdashboard.com/

Comment: Besides the logo, I think there's still an issue with your mobile navigation. The hovered menu item is not properly aligned with the active link.

Comment: I just checked your CSS and it doesn't contain a media query for the above?

Comment: meta tag is below of the css, so I think put meta tag on top of css.

Comment: Aeron is right, there is no string "width: 300px!important;" in your css on the page.

Comment: @Aaron and makadlcik 
I can see the code here 
http://www.geekdashboard.com/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_cd0be37ad66ab51354f355f3555beafc.css

CSS is minified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Specifying the media type should work fine.

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .header-image .site-title > a {
     background: url(images/logo-small.png) no-repeat left !important;
     width: 300px !important;
     }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
    .header-image .site-title > a {
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat left;
    float: left;
    min-height: 90px;
    width: 425px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, changed width to 424px from 320px and 425px in place of 321px and worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but seems cache is enabled on your site and it didn't changed "logo.png" to "logo-small.png" in your CSS - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujoUP.jpg

Probably try clearing your cache, it would help you!

Comment: may be cache issue, I cleared cache and tried this code and worked 
@ media only screen and (max-width: 424px) {
    .header-image .site-title > a {
     background: url(images/logo-small.png) no-repeat left !important;
     width: 300px !important;
     }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 425px) {
    .header-image .site-title > a {
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat left;
    float: left;
    min-height: 90px;
    width: 425px;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .header-image .site-title > a {
     background: url(images/logo-small.png) no-repeat left !important;
     width: 300px !important;
     }
}
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {

    .header-image .site-title > a {
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat left;
    float: left;
    min-height: 90px;
    width: 425px;
    }
}
```